# pyinstaller /waf failing even after installing c++

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

system: windows 10/64bit
Python: 3.6.7 /32-bit
pyinstaller - latest

I have set up a new system (the above) with python, eclipse IDE, and pyinstaller.

Initially I used pip install to install pyinstaller - but discovered I needed to download the source code. Ive downloaded the zip and extracted the source code.

I cd'd to the directory containing the script and attempted to compile a script using command

```
pyinstaller --onefile AXLSoapTest14.py
```

the script appeared to compile but the executable failed.

The execution of pyinstaller ran without warnings or errors however running the executable from an elevated command prompt gives these errors:

```
C:\Users\t01136\eclipse-workspace\AXLSoap4\dist>AXLSoapTest14.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AXLSoapTest14.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "test\test_tools\test_unparse.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "test\test_tools\__init__.py", line 17, in skip_if_missing
unittest.case.SkipTest: scripts directory could not be found
[12848] Failed to execute script AXLSoapTest14
```

In speaking with Mr Google, I found I may need to build the build the bootloader (tho I would have thought the install would fail outright).

I attempted to follow the instructions I found and CD'd to the bootloader folder of the extracted source code and attempted to execute:
python ./waf distclean all

I got the following errors:

````
 Pyinstaller\bootloader>python ./waf distclean all 
'distclean' finished successfully (0.001s)
'all' finished successfully (0.001s)
'distclean' finished successfully (0.001s)
Setting top to                           : C:\AXLdev\Python\pyinstaller\pyinstaller-develop\pyinstaller-develop\bootloader
Setting out to                           : C:\AXLdev\Python\pyinstaller\pyinstaller-develop\pyinstaller-develop\bootloader\build
Python Version                           : 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 12:45:02) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler)         : not found
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : not found
could not configure a C compiler!
(complete log in ```C:\AXLdev\Python\pyinstaller\pyinstaller-develop\pyinstaller-develop\bootloader\build\config.log)
````

I installed visual C++, rebooted and retried, but am getting the same error.

So the questions are:
Is my problem with the exe failing because the environment isnt set up?

If not, do I have 2 problems - one relating to the python waf command and then a second causing the compiled exe issue?

finally, what can I do to fix either or both of these problems?

The file Im trying to compile is over 1000 lines long so I didnt want to post it.

thanks for any help you can give!
w

Comment: I have resolved part of the problem - the portion where the executable created by pyinstaller failed.

Comment: Sorry - edit time on the comment above timed out - let me start over  ----------------------------  -I have resolved part of the problem - the portion where the executable created by pyinstaller failed.   I switched to py2exe, which gave better information on failure, and discovered I had a few unused imports that the compiler didnt like, and had a  module for which I had to download source - Colorama.   The compiled executables now run...  However I still have the problem with the    python ./waf distclean all    command. Any ideas?